# How to replace an element/node with in a list of child elements?

Tags: javascript

I have got a list of `<p>` elements within a `<DIV>` and i would like to replace the `<p>` with a new `<DIV>` when any of the `<p>` tags are clicked.

```
<div class="list">
 <p onClick="replaceWithDiv">para one</p>
 <p onClick="replaceWithDiv">para two</p>
 <p onClick="replaceWithDiv">para three</p>
</div>

when the second <p> is clicked I want it to change to

<div class="list">
 <p onClick="replaceWithDiv">para one</p>
 <div>NEW DIV</div>
 <p onClick="replaceWithDiv">para three</p>
</div>
```

How can I do this in javacsript?Any advice much appreciated

Comment: @Mahmoud sorry mate,i would like this in vanilla JS please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, post that code.

Comment: and if another <p> is clicked , do u want to replace the <div> with <p> again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.replaceChild)

```
function replaceWithDiv() 
    var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    //...
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(div, this);
}


<p onclick="replaceWithDiv.call(this)">para one</p>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call `replaceWithDiv` and pass `this` as a parameter?

Comment: @Ian: Why not? I prefer `this` to be current dom element.

Comment: Yeah I guess it doesn't matter, it can just get confusing if you call this function from other places...it seems easier to pass as a parameter instead of requiring the use of `call`

Comment: Well, actually I'd consider passing DOMElement as the first argument to be a bad practice. :) 
Since it makes it difficult to reuse the same function with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Very true :) So actually, I think the moral of the story, as it normally is, is not to use inline event handlers, and instead bind them manually with Javascript

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
function replaceWithDiv(obj) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'NEW DIV';
    obj.parentNode.insertBefore(div, obj);
    obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
}​
```

HTML:

```
<p onclick="replaceWithDiv(this)">para one</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/kcZYW/